# What's the meaning of "in the instance case"?

Tags: legalese, terminology

I've come across this phrase in legal documents. I've searched Google but couldn't find a definition. Google even treats it as a misspelling and says:  `Did you mean: "in the instant case"`

Some sample sentences:

- In the instance case, the defendant did not give a formal notice of its election to rebuild the house destroyed.
- In the instance case, therefore, the High Court had followed the
  correct procedure.

Can you please tell the meaning of it?

Comment: an instance = a legal proceeding or process; a suit.

Comment: https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/instant : "When composing a legal brief, an attorney might use the phrase the instant case in reference to the case currently before the court to distinguish it from other cases discussed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **instance** is a specific occurrence or example of something, such as an item produced from a template or a particular situation that reflects an abstract principle.

**instant** is an adjective formed from the noun **instance**, and means "being an instance" or "the instance under consideration".

> Crossing the street not at the corner but midway along its length is
>   an instance of  "jaywalking" if there is no crosswalk at the location.
>
> The instant case, Your Honor, sounds under contract.